# Why won't this snippet of code work?

Tags: php, strlen

I'm trying to set character limits for a register page and no matter what it says the username is too long can you guys tell me what's wrong? [see the error for your self](http://archeworlds.x10.mx/register)

```
    if(mb_strlen($uname) >= 20){
    if(mb_strlen($uname) <= 6){
    if(mb_strlen($pass1) <= 8){
    if(mb_strlen($pass1) >= 16){
    if((mb_strlen($email)) > 5 && strstr(($email1), "@") && strstr(($email1),".")){
        $pass = md5(md5("47Jdfio209".$pass1."4jfhioJasify3"));
        $pass = hash('sha512',$pass);


    $sql = $mysqli -> query("SELECT * FROM `archewor_users`.`users` WHERE `uname` = '$uname'");
    if(mysqli_num_rows($sql) > 0){
        echo"Sorry, that user already exists.";
    exit();

    }
    $mysqli -> query("INSERT INTO `archewor_users`.`users` (`id`, `name`, `lname`, `uname`, `email`, `pass`) VALUES (NULL, '$name', '$lname', '$uname', '$email1', '$pass')") or die(mysqli_error());
    }else{echo 'Your email must be valid.';}
    }else{echo 'This password is too long';}    
    }else{echo 'This password is too short';}
    }else{echo 'This username is too short';}

    }else{echo 'This username is too long';}

}else{
    echo "Sorry, your passwords do not match.<br />";   
    exit();
    }
}else{
    echo "Sorry, your emails do not match. <br /> <br />";
}




}else{
```

Comment: just paste your error here

Comment: The error is "This username is to long" even though it's not

Comment: Where do you set values for your variables? Besides, the way you are trying to check the conditions is quite odd.

Comment: This is just part of the code not the whole thing

Comment: do not you think that its pretty obvious that the script is not executing the code inside **if(mb_strlen($uname) >= 20)**. SO you need to check this **mb_strlen($uname)** value and post the code before it

Answer (score 0):

Logics written by you is incorrect. Check your if conditions for both username and passwords validation. Written code has very poor standard. Use conditional operators instead of nested if conditions.

Comment: Answer given by you@pkeidel is clearer and Logics can be understand by all. Is it your requirements- @user3053564

Answer (score 0):

It's only a logical error

```
// 1. Here you check, if your username is to LONG
// So your -else- is called, if your username is to SHORT
if(mb_strlen($uname) >= 20){
  // all the rest
} else {echo 'This username is too long';} // This message should be "Username is to short"
```

Maybe better:

```
if(mb_strlen($uname) >= 20)
  die("Username is to long");

if(mb_strlen($uname) <= 6)
  die("Username is to short");
```